# How much will Segwit increase the number of transactions that can fit in each block?

Tags: segregated-witness, block-size-increase, blocksize, witness-data

How much weight would the witness data have on the total block size? What is the culminating effect of this on the number of transactions that can fit into each block?

Thanks in advance :)